# VueJS hook mounted() is not called when page is re-open by vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Please, look the flux below, it's shows my problem. I'm using vue-router with `this.$router.push` to browsing on pages. I'm starting on PageA.

- PageA -> PageB ( `mounted()` of PageB is called)
- PageB -> PageA (returning to PageA)
- PageA -> PageB (`mounted()` of PageB is not called)

It sounds that page (.vue component) is not closed and mainted on cache or other thing. I must use the `mounted()` method every time that page is open and maybe close the page and clean from cache. How I can solve it?

Answer (score 6):

`vue` will re-use components were possible, this is expected.
Normally you would watch for route changes and update your component state accordingly.

To react to route changes you can use [`beforeRouteUpdate()`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation):

```js
const Example = Vue.extend({
  template: `
   <div>
    <p>This changes: '{{param}}'</p>
    </div>`,
  data(){
    return {
      param: this.$route.params.param
    };
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    this.param = to.params.param;
    next();
  }
});

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/:param', component: Example,
    }
  ]
})
const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/foo">foo</router-link><br>
  <router-link to="/bar">bar</router-link><br>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can also watch the route and update the state accordingly:

```
Vue.extend({
  watch: {
    '$route'() {
      // TODO: react to navigation event.
      // params cotains the current route parameters
      console.log(this.$route.params);
    }
  },
  // ....
});
```

The `vue-router` documentation has a few great examples for this: [Data Fetching - Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#data-fetching)

If you still want to use `mounted()`, you can do so by giving your `router-view` a key that will change when the route changes, e.g.:

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

This will force the component to be re-created every time, so it does have a performance penalty - i would recommend using the route hooks described above, if possible.

Comment: Your explanation was productive but your solution not solved my problem. 1. I followed your code tips but not worked to me. 2. My project is very big and I can't edit the `<router-view>` because very people works them. I need a solution that can be implemented on the specific component.

Comment: @Augusto what kind of logic do you have in your `mount()` hook? could you post it? what are the routes, how do they change? - There is unfortunately no way for a component to unmount & remount itself - `mount()` will only be called once - the only way you can force a component to be re-mounted is to give it a key - which in this case unfortunately has to be on the `router-view` if your component gets rendered from a route

Comment: In my `mount()` I must read `state` to get pre-selected or reset form's data. Imagine the follow behavior, the user open form page and edit it, but when him closes the page the form must be reseted, but, like vuejs re-use component the form is re-used and the data is not reseted.

Comment: Reading others questions, the `key` and `watchers` sounds be a solution but I don't know use them.

Comment: then you could move the code from your `mount()` hook into a method and call that one from `mount()` and `beforeRouteUpdate()`. If you also want to clear the data of your component you can additionally use `Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())` in your `beforeRouteUpdate` hook

Comment: Sorry, I don't got it. But navigation guards is called on main component, and the component that I speaked is a off canvas. How I would use it: `Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())` on beforeRouteUpdate?

Comment: @Augusto heres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foqduanb/2/) - if your component is not directly a route, you can use the watch `$route` option (my second example)

Answer (score 4):

## Vue 3

For those that ended up here like me looking at why I'm not getting **unmounted** called on a component inside a page, when route changes, here's some guidance:

Let's say you have *Page A* that uses *Component A* in it, and *Page B* that does not use *Component A*.

When you open *Page A* for the first time, *Component A* will have, as expected, [mounted](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#mounted) method called.

However, when you navigate to *Page B*, Vue3 won't un-mount or destroy *Component A*, rather it will deactivate it, and [deactivated](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#deactivated) method will be called instead of [unmounted](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#unmounted).

Once you navigate back to *Page A*, *Component A* will be reactivated and method [activated](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#activated) will be called instead of *mounted*.

Comment: This feature was added on Vue3?

Comment: @Augusto tested in my current project. This is the first project I use Vue 3 so it's pretty new to me as well how their component life cycle works now.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using the **Composition API** for **Vue 3**:

This use case is for fetching data from an API upon component mount and other dependencies. Instead of `watch`, you need to use [`watchEffect`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect) to automatically track the dependencies and perform side effects on mount.

```
watchEffect(fetchData);
```

`watch(dependencies, callback)` will trigger on first visit to the route. But if you go to another page, then come back to it, it won't trigger again because it does not count the initial state as an update. Also, the dependencies technically did not change from the time it was mounted.

Additional Notes:

- If you are coming from React, `watch` is not exactly equivalent to `useEffect`. `watchEffect` is more similar to it.
- For comparison, this code should have the same results as the `watchEffect` one. But `watchEffect` is more concise.

```
onMounted(fetchData);
watch([dependency 1, dependency 2, ...], fetchData);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ionic Framework Vue3

Also for those that ended up here like me looking at why the hooks dont work!, refer to the ionic [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/lifecycle) lifecycle changes on ion-router-outlet.

Hope to save lots of hours that cost for me.